# I can't figure out why the output is undefined

Tags: javascript, quicksort

```
function greatestProduct(array,start,end) {
    if(end - start <= 0){
        let productValue = array[array.length - 1] * array[array.length - 2] * array[array.length - 3];
        return productValue;
    }
    
    let pivot = partition(array,start,end);
    greatestProduct(array, start, pivot - 1);
    greatestProduct(array, pivot + 1, end);
}

function partition(array, leftPointer, rightPointer) {
    const pivotIndex = rightPointer;
    const pivotValue = array[pivotIndex];
    rightPointer -= 1;
    while(true) {
        while(array[leftPointer] < pivotValue){
            leftPointer += 1;
        }
        while(array[rightPointer] > pivotValue){
            rightPointer -= 1;
        }
        if(leftPointer >= rightPointer){
            break;
        }
        else
            [array[leftPointer], array[rightPointer]] = [array[rightPointer], array[leftPointer]];
            leftPointer += 1;
    }
    [array[leftPointer], array[pivotIndex]] = [array[pivotIndex], array[leftPointer]];
    return leftPointer;
}


let myArray = [2,4,1,6,3,5];
console.log(greatestProduct(myArray,0, myArray.length - 1));
```

I am trying to use Quick Sort to first sort the array and find the product of the three greatest numbers in the array. However, I kept getting a undefined output and I can't identify which part of the code is wrong.I am still practicing on Quick Sort and Recursion so don't mind my carelessness xd

Comment: `greatestProduct` only returns a value in the case `(end - start <= 0)`; the recursive calls return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the code itself, since it is the solution you have come up with, although it is not the most optimal, your problem is that your function «greatestProduct» is a recursive function, but you only return a value at end of the recursion, but losses it when return to the previous recursive caller...

Try

```
function greatestProduct(array,start,end) {
    console.log(end, start,end - start);
    if(end - start <= 0){
        let productValue = array[array.length - 1] * array[array.length - 2] * array[array.length - 3];
        return productValue;
    }
    
    let pivot = partition(array,start,end);
    greatestProduct(array, start, pivot - 1);
    return greatestProduct(array, pivot + 1, end);
}
```

This will fix your "undefined" output